# ng-table grouping when sorting/filtering

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table grouping (http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-api), I was able to group data and display it. If the group is expanded and click on the sort/filtering the group is collapsed again. Is there anyway to avoid this behavior,i,e keep the expanded group open even if sorting or filtering is done

Comment: Do you want just opened column remained open or if all columns open. Would it do your need ?

Comment: Yes when particular group is expanded. It should remain open even if sorting or filtering is done

Answer (score 0):

As of v1.0.0 this is not possible by default. You can however try to hack your way around. A Pull Request to the official repository would be highly appreciated.
If the ng-table will update in the upcoming future and provide the functionality you want, I'll update this answer.